# Ember route and navigation in modal, keeping parent route visible

Tags: ember.js

Is it possible to have a route, say `images/` show a list of images, and on click have an image open in a modal/viewer, say `images/viewer/10`, that has navigation (previous links to `images/viewer/9`, next links to `images/viewer/11`), updating the viewer modal while keeping the background `images/` behind the modal as is, so that you can cancel the modal and go back to `images/` without reloading the route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see https://ember-twiddle.com/1da304530ea1367389361213fcf839c6?openFiles=templates.images.hbs%2C

You can define your routes like this:

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('images', function() {
    this.route('viewer', {path: "/viewer/:id"});
  });
});
```

Pay attention in file structure in twiddle (images parent route for outlet and viewer nested route for modal, not images index route).

And then, you can show the modal viewer template in an outlet defined in images template.

Well, when you navigate to /images, you will see images template, without the modal. And the route's hooks will have executed.
From images, if you navigate to /images/viwer/x, the viewer route hooks will execute, but not images, because have already been executed.
When you navigate from images/viewer/x to /images will do the same (images route hooks will not execute one more time).

Hope this helps.
regards

Comment: This helps! Thank you.